# How to retrieve associations together with authenticated user data?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have a `Users` table and a `UsersProfiles` table - the two are obviously related and the user table stores basic `user_id`, `username`, `password` while the users_profiles table stores `firstname`, `lastname`, `job_title` etc.

In CakePHP 3, the call to Authentication Component on login returns the basic user table row. I would like to modify the same to also return the corresponding profile row. How can I do this?

I found a way to do it - but am not sure if there is a more elegant or simpler way.

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                // load profile and associate with user object
                $profile = $this->Users->UsersProfiles->get($user['id']);
                $user['users_profile'] = $profile;
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->config('loginRedirect'));
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The `contain` option

Before CakePHP 3.1, use the `contain` option

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'contain' => ['UsersProfiles']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

### A custom finder

As of 3.1 you can use the `finder` option to define the finder to use for building the query that fetches the user data

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'finder' => 'auth'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

In your table class

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->contain(['UsersProfiles']);
}
```

### Both solutions

will ensure that the data returned by `AuthComponent::identify()` will contain the associated `UsersProfiles`.

### See also

- **[Cookbook > ... Components > Authentication > Configuring Authentication Handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)**
- **[Cookbook > ... Components > Authentication > Customizing find query](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)**

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, but your solution is not paid, how do I recover the data from the UsersProfiles table?

Comment: @IsaacPalacio I don't know what exactly you are trying to say, but the examples shown in the answer do work. If you are having problems implementing this, then you may want to open a new question where you can properly elaborate on the specific problem that you are facing, show your code, etc...

Comment: Hello, sorry for the inconvenience, but I already solve it, but do not contain, but using join, also thanks