# cakePHP3 linking tables from template files

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

Well, this might be a basic question. Because I'm absolutely new to cakePHP 3.0 thus, I still dont clearly understand its structure. I hope that somebody might elaborate this to me.

I have those table:

- Users(id, username, password, role)
- Customers(id, user_id, fname, lname, email, ...)
- Employees(id, user_id, fname, lname, ...)

Suppose that the user has successfully logged in. I can use this code to get information from the Users table from my default.ctp template.

```
<?php 
    try{
       $user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
?>
```

Then I can access any attribute from the Users table such as $user['username'], $user['password'], etc.

However, what I want is to display the current logged in user's first name and last name which are stored in the Customers and Employees tables. How could I access those details in the default.ctp file?

Kind Regards.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific, like, does the associated data exist in your user data, and you don't know how to access nested arrays, or doesn't it exist, and you don't know how to make the auth component include it?

Comment: thanks ndm, the Auth Component can basically get data in the User table only. Is there a way to make the auth component to include associated data as well? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve associations together with authenticated user data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661318/how-to-retrieve-associations-together-with-authenticated-user-data)