# CakePHP 3 foreign key in view

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 tables: Users, Levels

Users have fields: id, username, password, email, level_id
Levels have fields: id, name

In UsersController i want send user data and his foreign key to view.

```
 $user = $this->Auth->User();
 $this->set(compact('user'));
```

In view i want display level name of this user. How can i do that?

I was trying:

```
$user->level;
$user->username->level
$user->level_id->name
```

Ofc. didnt work. What i do wrong?

I just started learn CakePHP and this stoped me because i never used 
foreignkey before.

Comment: Do you have [model associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) set up between Users and Levels?

Comment: By default, $this->Auth->user() return just User table. If You want get more information in this method, You should use custom finder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661318/how-to-retrieve-associations-together-with-authenticated-user-data/32669470#32669470

Comment: "I just started learn CakePHP" - and obviously didn't read the query builder or association section of the manual. Do yourself a big favor and do the tutorials in the manual. They'll teach all the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cakephp assocations for the same. First of all add one more field in **`Levels`** table named **`user_id`**.

Assuming a user has one to one relation with level. Then create a file named **UsersTable.php** under **/src/Model/Table** folder and define your model association there as follow

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasOne('Levels');
    }
}
```

Now you can execute your find query in your `UsersController` as below:

```
 $user = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['Users.id' => $id])->contain(['Levels'])->toArray();
 $this->set(compact('user'));
```

Then on your ctp file you can access level name as:

```
echo $user['level']['name'];
```

For further reading associations:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Query Builder:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html