# In cakephp 3.6, How to change user finder query for auth component?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.6

For cakephp 3.6, cakephp.org tell how to customise user finder query for auth component at following link:
[link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)
But I am not getting how to implement it? 
I have 'department_id' column in users table which belongs to departments table. I want to change the following query:

```
public function findAuth(){
    $query
    ->select(['id', 'username', 'password'])->contain(['Departments'])
        ->where(['Users.active' => 1]);
    return $query;
}
```

Will the above code work? 
Please tell me in which file I have to write the function?
And what are other necessary steps to get it done, so that I get all user related info in $this->Auth->User ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to load the Auth component and pass in custom configuration in any controller that you want to use the custom finder like so:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
    ]);
}
```

then, in your `UsersTable` you would have the custom finder:

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
    ->select(['id', 'username', 'password'])->contain(['Departments'])
    ->where(['Users.active' => 1]);

    return $query;
}
```

This answer may also help [Containing tables in custom Auth finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661318/how-to-retrieve-associations-together-with-authenticated-user-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)